# Resize images with (4:3) PHP

Tags: php, image

In the page I manage, the user can upload an image of any in dimension, being no more than 1 MB of space. I want to resize the image relative to 240x180 px but without breaking the aspect ratio of the image (or at least that it will not be greatly distorted). My current code only changes the image forcefully:

```
$img = imagecreatetruecolor ($width, $height);
imagecopyresampled ($img, $original_img, 0,0,0,0, $width, $height, $wimg, $h_img);
```

I want to generate an image (when it is the case) with the same aspect of relation that is loaded, but less than `$width` and `$height` target, and what remains fill with black margo.

"It's like I have the black background and place the image centered on the"

Comment: Correction:- `$ img`  need to be `$img` and so on for others. (remove space)

Comment: Do you want to fit the image in a 240x180 box by keeping ratio. an image of sized 480x180 will be resized to 240x90 leaving 45px blank at top and bottom. Right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, this will give the values for [imagecopyresampled](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php)

```
<?php

$x = 1000 ; //sample width
$y = 768 ;  //sample height

$ratio = 4/3;
$newRatio = $x/$y ; //ratio of given sample.

$decision = $y * $ratio ;

//height need to be adjusted
if( $decision < $x ) {

    $width = 240 ;
    $height = 240 / $newRatio ;
}
//width must be adjusted
else if( $decision > $x ) {

    $width = 180 * $newRatio;
    $height = 180  ;
}
//already in proportion
else {
    $width = 240 ;
    $height = 180 ;
}

$dst_w = floor($width) ;
$dst_h = floor($height) ;

//give half of the total margin to left and top.
$dst_x = floor( (240 - $dst_w) / 2 ) ;
$dst_y = floor( (180 - $dst_h) / 2 ) ;

echo "Width & Height:" . $dst_w . ' x ' . $dst_h ;
echo "<br/>";
echo "Dst X & Y :" .$dst_x . ' x ' . $dst_y ;
```